# Create a database

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I want to try to create a database but I get the following error:

> Error Code: 1192. Can't execute the given command because you have active locked tables or an active transaction.

The database that I want to create is related to a bank whose tables are: customer, account and operation.
I don't know if I really have PK's or FK's but when creating it I get that error.

```
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema Bank
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `Bank` ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `Bank`.`Customer`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Bank`.`Customer` (
  `idCustomer` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `lastname` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `DNI` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  `phone` INT(10) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idCustomer`)
 ) ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `Bank`.`Account`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Bank`.`Account` (
  `idAccount` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Customer_idCustomer` INT NOT NULL,
  `numAccount` INT(10) NOT NULL,
  `accountType` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `balance` FLOAT (10) NOT NULL,
  `currency` VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idAccount`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`Customer_idCustomer`) REFERENCES `Bank`.`Customer`(idCustomer) ON DELETE CASCADE
  )
ENGINE = InnoDB;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `Bank`.`Transaction`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Bank`.`Transaction` (
  `idTransaction` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Customer_idCustomer` INT NOT NULL,
  `Account_idAccount` INT NOT NULL,
  `transactionType` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `transactionDate` DATE  NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idTransaction`),
  CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (`Customer_idCustomer`) REFERENCES `Bank`.`Customer`(idCustomer) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  UNIQUE KEY (idTransaction),
  FOREIGN KEY (`Account_idAccount`) REFERENCES `Bank`.`Account`(idAccount) ON DELETE CASCADE
  )
ENGINE = InnoDB;


SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;
```

I'm not sure if I have the database well implemented

Comment: workbench doesn't mind, so where Do you run it?

Comment: You probably need to create the tables without the foreign key references, load the data, and then alter in the foreign key dependencies.

Comment: I run it in workbench @nbk

Comment: reboot your server, there is something not right, also check the error logs and see if there is  something.

Comment: I have done it several times and nothing @nbk

Comment: how can you have a lock on a new database. lock can only be done by updates, so drop teh schema, check if there are events or trigger that could lock the table.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be so easy that you have running transactions that are not commited yet?
Or that the word  `transaction` are an reserved word?

Comment: hi, there are no transactions running.